# make using autotools gives undefined reference errors while custom Makefile works fine

Tags: c, linux, makefile, autotools, automake

I'm trying to convert the build mechanism of ccextractor (Open source closed caption extractor) from custom Makefile to Autotools generated Makefile.

Current Makefile looks like this:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh

CC = gcc
SYS := $(shell gcc -dumpmachine)
CFLAGS = -O3 -std=gnu99 -s
INCLUDE = -Isrc/gpacmp4/ -Isrc/libpng -Isrc/lib_hash -Isrc/protobuf-c -Isrc/zlib -Isrc/lib_ccx -Isrc/.
INCLUDE += -Isrc/zvbi -Isrc/utf8proc
ALL_FLAGS = -Wno-write-strings -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVERSION_FILE_PRESENT
LDFLAGS = -lm

ifneq (, $(findstring linux, $(SYS)))
CFLAGS +=-DGPAC_CONFIG_LINUX
endif
TARGET = ccextractor

OBJS_DIR = objs
VPATH = src:src/gpacmp4:src/libpng:src/zlib:src/lib_ccx:src/zvbi:src/lib_hash:src/utf8proc:src/protobuf-c

SRCS_DIR = src
SRCS_C = $(wildcard $(SRCS_DIR)/*.c)
OBJS = $(SRCS_C:$(SRCS_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o)

SRCS_CCX_DIR = $(SRCS_DIR)/lib_ccx
SRCS_CCX = $(wildcard $(SRCS_CCX_DIR)/*.c)
OBJS_CCX = $(SRCS_CCX:$(SRCS_CCX_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o)

SRCS_PNG_DIR = $(SRCS_DIR)/libpng
SRCS_PNG = $(wildcard $(SRCS_PNG_DIR)/*.c)
OBJS_PNG = $(SRCS_PNG:$(SRCS_PNG_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o)

SRCS_ZVBI_DIR = $(SRCS_DIR)/zvbi
SRCS_ZVBI = $(wildcard $(SRCS_ZVBI_DIR)/*.c)
OBJS_ZVBI = $(SRCS_ZVBI:$(SRCS_ZVBI_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o)

SRCS_GPACMP4_DIR = $(SRCS_DIR)/gpacmp4
SRCS_GPACMP4_C = $(wildcard $(SRCS_GPACMP4_DIR)/*.c)
SRCS_GPACMP4_CPP = $(wildcard $(SRCS_GPACMP4_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJS_GPACMP4 = $(SRCS_GPACMP4_C:$(SRCS_GPACMP4_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o) \
               $(SRCS_GPACMP4_CPP:$(SRCS_GPACMP4_DIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o)

SRCS_ZLIB_DIR = $(SRCS_DIR)/zlib
SRCS_ZLIB = $(wildcard $(SRCS_ZLIB_DIR)/*.c)
OBJS_ZLIB = $(SRCS_ZLIB:$(SRCS_ZLIB_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o)

SRCS_HASH_DIR = $(SRCS_DIR)/lib_hash
SRCS_HASH = $(wildcard $(SRCS_HASH_DIR)/*.c)
OBJS_HASH = $(SRCS_HASH:$(SRCS_HASH_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o)

SRCS_UTF8_DIR = $(SRCS_DIR)/utf8proc
SRCS_UTF8 = $(SRCS_UTF8_DIR)/utf8proc.c
OBJS_UTF8 = $(SRCS_UTF8:$(SRCS_UTF8_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o)

INSTLALL = cp -f -p
INSTLALL_PROGRAM = $(INSTLALL)
DESTDIR = /usr/bin

ifeq ($(ENABLE_HARDSUBX),yes)
ENABLE_OCR=yes
CFLAGS+=-DENABLE_HARDSUBX
CFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --cflags libavcodec)
CFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --cflags libavformat)
CFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --cflags libavutil)
CFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --cflags libswscale)
AV_LDFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --libs libavcodec )
AV_LDFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --libs libavformat )
AV_LDFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --libs libavutil )
AV_LDFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --libs libswscale )
ifeq ($(AV_LDFLAGS),$(EMPTY))
$(error **ERROR** "libav not found")
else
$(info "libav found")
endif
LDFLAGS+= $(AV_LDFLAGS)
endif

ifeq ($(ENABLE_OCR),yes)
CFLAGS+=-DENABLE_OCR -DPNG_NO_CONFIG_H
LEPT_LDFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --libs lept)

ifneq ($(shell pkg-config --exists tesseract), $(EMPTY))
TESS_LDFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --libs tesseract)
TESS_CFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --cflags tesseract)
else
#fix for raspberry pi not having a pkgconfig file for tesseract
ifneq ($(wildcard /usr/include/tesseract/*),$(EMPTY))
TESS_LDFLAGS+= -ltesseract
TESS_CFLAGS+= -I/usr/include/tesseract
endif
endif

#error checking of library are there or not
ifeq ($(TESS_LDFLAGS),$(EMPTY))
$(error **ERROR** "tesseract not found")
else
#TODO print the version of library found
$(info  "tesseract found")
endif

ifeq ($(LEPT_LDFLAGS),$(EMPTY))
$(error **ERROR** "leptonica not found")
else
#TODO print the version of library found
$(info  "Leptonica found")
endif

CFLAGS  += $(TESS_CFLAGS)
CFLAGS  += $(shell pkg-config --cflags lept)
LDFLAGS += $(TESS_LDFLAGS)
LDFLAGS += $(LEPT_LDFLAGS)
endif


ifeq ($(ENABLE_FFMPEG),yes)
CFLAGS+=-DENABLE_FFMPEG
CFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --cflags libavcodec)
CFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --cflags libavformat)
CFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --cflags libavutil)
LDFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --libs libavcodec )
LDFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --libs libavformat )
LDFLAGS+= $(shell pkg-config --libs libavutil )
endif

.PHONY: all
all: pre-build objs_dir $(TARGET) 

.PHONY: objs_dir
objs_dir: 
    mkdir -p $(OBJS_DIR)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS) $(OBJS_PNG) $(OBJS_GPACMP4) $(OBJS_ZVBI) $(OBJS_ZLIB) $(OBJS_HASH) $(OBJS_CCX) $(OBJS_UTF8)
    $(CC) $(ALL_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(OBJS_CCX) $(OBJS_PNG) $(OBJS_ZVBI) $(OBJS_GPACMP4) $(OBJS_ZLIB) $(OBJS_HASH) $(OBJS_UTF8) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(ALL_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@  

$(OBJS_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(ALL_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ -Isrc/gpacmp4 

$(OBJS_DIR)/ccextractor.o: ccextractor.c
    $(CC) -c $(ALL_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) -O0 $< -o $@  

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET) 2>/dev/null || true
    rm -rf $(OBJS_CCX) $(OBJS_PNG) $(OBJS_ZLIB) $(OBJS_GPACMP4) $(OBJS_HASH) $(OBJS_UTF8) $(OBJS) 2>/dev/null || true
    rm -rdf $(OBJS_DIR) 2>/dev/null || true
    rm -rf .depend 2>/dev/null || true

.PHONY: install
install: $(TARGET)
    $(INSTLALL_PROGRAM) $(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)

.PHONY: uninstall
uninstall: 
    rm -iv $(DESTDIR)/$(TARGET) 

.PHONY: depend dep
depend dep:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -E -MM $(SRCS_C) $(SRCS_PNG) $(SRCS_ZVBI) $(SRCS_ZLIB) $(SRCS_HASH) $(SRCS_UTF8) $(SRCS_CCX) \
        $(SRCS_GPACMP4_C) $(SRCS_GPACMP4_CPP) |\
        sed 's/^[a-zA-Z_0-9]*.o/$(OBJS_DIR)\/&/' > .depend

.PHONY: pre-build
pre-build:
    ./pre-build.sh

-include .depend
```

Building through above Makefile works fine. My Makefile.am looks like this:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = ccextractor
ccextractor_SOURCES = \
                **Removing common content of Makefile.am as below due to maximum character limit**

AM_CPPFLAGS = -I src -I /usr/include/leptonica/ -I /usr/include/tesseract/ -I src/lib_ccx/ -I src/gpacmp4/ -I src/libpng/ -I src/zlib/ -I src/zvbi/ -I src/lib_hash/ -I src/protobuf-c/ -I src/utf8proc/

AM_CFLAGS = -std=gnu99 -Wno-write-strings -DGPAC_CONFIG_LINUX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVERSION_FILE_PRESENT -DENABLE_OCR

AM_LDFLAGS = -lm -lz -ltesseract -llept
```

If I run `make` after `autoreconf -i` on above file, build fails with error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: src/gpacmp4/av_parsers.o: undefined reference to symbol 'trunc@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

If I run `./configure` as `./configure LIBS="-lm -lz"` build fails with errors as:

```
/media/mayank/Mayank/GSOC 2017/Projects/ccextractor/src/gpacmp4/drm_sample.c:1358: undefined reference to `gf_isom_get_track_from_file'
src/gpacmp4/drm_sample.o: In function `gf_isom_get_adobe_protection_info':
/media/mayank/Mayank/GSOC 2017/Projects/ccextractor/src/gpacmp4/drm_sample.c:1378: undefined reference to `gf_isom_get_track_from_file'
/media/mayank/Mayank/GSOC 2017/Projects/ccextractor/src/gpacmp4/drm_sample.c:1387: undefined reference to `IsMP4Description'
src/gpacmp4/drm_sample.o: In function `gf_isom_cenc_is_pattern_mode':
/media/mayank/Mayank/GSOC 2017/Projects/ccextractor/src/gpacmp4/drm_sample.c:1401: undefined reference to `gf_isom_get_track_from_file'
src/gpacmp4/drm_sample.o: In function `gf_isom_ipmpx_remove_tool_list':
/media/mayank/Mayank/GSOC 2017/Projects/ccextractor/src/gpacmp4/drm_sample.c:1421: undefined reference to `gf_odf_desc_del'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`tree` in `src` dir is:

```
.
├── ccextractor.c
├── CCExtractorConfig.h.in
├── ccextractor.o
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── gpacmp4
│   ├── avc_ext.c
│   ├── avc_ext.o
│   ├── avilib.c
│   ├── avilib.o
│   ├── av_parsers.c
│   ├── drm_sample.o
│   ├── error.c
│   ├── error.o
│   ├── gpac
│   │   ├── avparse.h
│   │   ├── base_coding.h
│   │   ├── bitstream.h
│   │   ├── config_file.h
│   │   ├── configuration.h
│   │   ├── constants.h
│   │   ├── events_constants.h
│   │   ├── ietf.h
│   │   ├── internal
│   │   │   ├── avilib.h
│   │   │   ├── isomedia_dev.h
│   │   │   ├── media_dev.h
│   │   │   ├── odf_dev.h
│   │   │   ├── odf_parse_common.h
│   │   │   └── ogg.h
│   │   ├── isomedia.h
│   │   ├── list.h
│   │   ├── math.h
│   │   ├── media_tools.h
│   │   ├── mpeg4_odf.h
│   │   ├── network.h
│   │   ├── revision.h
│   │   ├── setup.h
│   │   ├── sync_layer.h
│   │   ├── tools.h
│   │   ├── utf.h
│   │   └── version.h
│   ├── gpac_ogg.c
│   ├── hinting.c
│   ├── ipmpx_code.c
│   ├── ipmpx_parse.c
│   ├── isom_intern.c
│   ├── isom_read.c
│   ├── isom_store.c
│   ├── isom_write.c
│   ├── list.c
│   ├── math.c
│   ├── media.c
│   ├── media_odf.c
│   ├── meta.c
│   ├── movie_fragments.c
│   ├── mp4.c
│   ├── odf_code.c
│   ├── odf_codec.c
│   ├── odf_command.c
│   ├── os_config_init.c
│   ├── os_divers.c
│   ├── os_file.c
│   ├── qos.c
│   ├── ReadMe.txt
│   ├── sample_descs.c
│   ├── slc.c
│   ├── stbl_read.c
│   ├── stbl_write.c
│   ├── track.c
│   ├── tx3g.c
│   ├── url.c
│   └── utf.c
├── lib_ccx
│   ├── activity.c
│   ├── activity.h
│   ├── asf_constants.h
│   ├── asf_functions.c
│   ├── avc_functions.c
│   ├── avc_functions.h
│   ├── bitstream.h
│   ├── cc_bitstream.c
│   ├── ccfont2.xbm
│   ├── ccx_common_char_encoding.c
│   ├── ccx_common_char_encoding.h
│   ├── ccx_decoders_708.h
│   ├── ccx_decoders_708_output.c
│   ├── ccx_encoders_xds.h
│   ├── ccx_gxf.c
│   ├── ccx_gxf.h
│   ├── ccx_mp4.h
│   ├── dvd_subtitle_decoder.c
│   ├── utility.h
│   ├── wtv_constants.h
│   └── wtv_functions.c
├── lib_hash
│   ├── README
│   ├── sha2.c
│   └── sha2.h
├── libpng
│   ├── png.c
│   ├── pngconf.h
│   ├── pngdebug.h
│   ├── pngerror.c
│   ├── pngget.c
|   |
├── protobuf-c
│   ├── protobuf-c.c
│   └── protobuf-c.h
├── utf8proc
│   ├── utf8proc.c
│   ├── utf8proc_data.c
│   └── utf8proc.h
├── win_iconv
│   ├── iconv.h
│   └── win_iconv.c
├── win_spec_incld
│   ├── dirent.h
│   ├── inttypes.h
│   └── stdint.h
├── zlib
│   ├── adler32.c
│   ├── compress.c
│   ├── crc32.c
│   ├── crc32.h
│   ├── deflate.c
│   ├── deflate.h
│   ├── gzclose.c
│   ├── gzguts.h
│   ├── zutil.c
│   └── zutil.h
└── zvbi
    ├── bcd.h
    ├── bit_slicer.c
    ├── bit_slicer.h
    ├── decoder.c
    ├── macros.h
    ├── misc.h
    ├── raw_decoder.c
    ├── raw_decoder.h
    ├── sampling_par.c
    ├── sampling_par.h
    ├── sliced.h
    └── zvbi_decoder.h
**Stripped some filenames (not directory) due to max character limit**
```

And also, all includes are done with full path in sub directories of `src`, like for a file in `gpacmp4` directory, `#include <gpac/avparse.h>`. All but the main `ccextractor.c` file, for which all the `-I flags` are provided.

To refer ccextractor original code:
https://github.com/CCExtractor/ccextractor

The original `Makefile` will be in `linux` directory.

PS: Currently I'm trying to get the ccextractor build all the checks will be introduced later. For simplified mechanism `ccextractor/linux/build` is useful to refer.

Even the slightest help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:** (courtesy of @MadScientist)
I updated `Makefile.am` as:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign

bin_PROGRAMS = ccextractor
ccextractor_SOURCES = \
                src/ccextractor.c \
                src/gpacmp4/avc_ext.c \
                src/gpacmp4/avilib.c \
                src/gpacmp4/av_parsers.c \
                src/gpacmp4/base_encoding.c \
                src/gpacmp4/bitstream.c \
                src/gpacmp4/box_code_3gpp.c \
                src/gpacmp4/box_code_adobe.c \
                src/gpacmp4/box_code_apple.c \
                src/gpacmp4/box_code_base.c \
                src/gpacmp4/box_code_drm.c \
                src/gpacmp4/box_code_meta.c \
                src/gpacmp4/box_funcs.c \
                src/gpacmp4/configfile.c \
                src/gpacmp4/data_map.c \
                src/gpacmp4/desc_private.c \
                src/gpacmp4/descriptors.c \
                src/gpacmp4/drm_sample.c \
                src/gpacmp4/error.c \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/avparse.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/base_coding.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/bitstream.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/config_file.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/configuration.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/constants.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/events_constants.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/ietf.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/internal
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/internal/avilib.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/internal/isomedia_dev.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/internal/media_dev.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/internal/odf_dev.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/internal/odf_parse_common.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/internal/ogg.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/isomedia.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/list.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/math.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/media_tools.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/mpeg4_odf.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/network.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/revision.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/setup.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/sync_layer.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/tools.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/utf.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac/version.h \
                src/gpacmp4/gpac_ogg.c \
                src/gpacmp4/hinting.c \
                src/gpacmp4/ipmpx_code.c \
                src/gpacmp4/ipmpx_parse.c \
                src/gpacmp4/isom_intern.c \
                src/gpacmp4/isom_read.c \
                src/gpacmp4/isom_store.c \
                src/gpacmp4/isom_write.c \
                src/gpacmp4/list.c \
                src/gpacmp4/math.c \
                src/gpacmp4/media.c \
                src/gpacmp4/media_odf.c \
                src/gpacmp4/meta.c \
                src/gpacmp4/movie_fragments.c \
                src/gpacmp4/mp4.c \
                src/gpacmp4/odf_code.c \
                src/gpacmp4/odf_codec.c \
                src/gpacmp4/odf_command.c \
                src/gpacmp4/os_config_init.c \
                src/gpacmp4/os_divers.c \
                src/gpacmp4/os_file.c \
                src/gpacmp4/qos.c \
                src/gpacmp4/ReadMe.txt
                src/gpacmp4/sample_descs.c \
                src/gpacmp4/slc.c \
                src/gpacmp4/stbl_read.c \
                src/gpacmp4/stbl_write.c \
                src/gpacmp4/track.c \
                src/gpacmp4/tx3g.c \
                src/gpacmp4/url.c \
                src/gpacmp4/utf.c \
                src/lib_ccx/activity.c \
                src/lib_ccx/activity.h \
                src/lib_ccx/asf_constants.h \
                src/lib_ccx/asf_functions.c \
                src/lib_ccx/avc_functions.c \
                src/lib_ccx/avc_functions.h \
                src/lib_ccx/bitstream.h \
                src/lib_ccx/cc_bitstream.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_common_char_encoding.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_common_char_encoding.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_common_common.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_common_common.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_common_constants.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_common_constants.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_common_option.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_common_option.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_common_platform.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_common_structs.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_common_timing.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_common_timing.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_608.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_608.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_708.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_708_encoding.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_708_encoding.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_708.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_708_output.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_708_output.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_common.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_common.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_isdb.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_isdb.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_structs.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_vbi.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_vbi.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_xds.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_decoders_xds.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_demuxer.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_demuxer.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_dtvcc.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_dtvcc.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_common.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_common.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_curl.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_g608.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_helpers.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_helpers.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_sami.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_smptett.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_splitbysentence.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_spupng.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_spupng.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_srt.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_ssa.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_structs.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_transcript.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_webvtt.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_xds.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_encoders_xds.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_gxf.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_gxf.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_mp4.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_share.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_share.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_sub_entry_message.pb-c.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ccx_sub_entry_message.pb-c.h \
                src/lib_ccx/CMakeLists.txt
                src/lib_ccx/compile_info.h \
                src/lib_ccx/compile_info_real.h \
                src/lib_ccx/configuration.c \
                src/lib_ccx/configuration.h \
                src/lib_ccx/disable_warnings.h \
                src/lib_ccx/dvb_subtitle_decoder.c \
                src/lib_ccx/dvb_subtitle_decoder.h \
                src/lib_ccx/dvd_subtitle_decoder.c \
                src/lib_ccx/dvd_subtitle_decoder.h \
                src/lib_ccx/es_functions.c \
                src/lib_ccx/es_userdata.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ffmpeg_intgr.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ffmpeg_intgr.h \
                src/lib_ccx/file_buffer.h \
                src/lib_ccx/file_functions.c \
                src/lib_ccx/general_loop.c \
                src/lib_ccx/hamming.h \
                src/lib_ccx/hardsubx.c \
                src/lib_ccx/hardsubx_classifier.c \
                src/lib_ccx/hardsubx_decoder.c \
                src/lib_ccx/hardsubx.h \
                src/lib_ccx/hardsubx_imgops.c \
                src/lib_ccx/hardsubx_utility.c \
                src/lib_ccx/lib_ccx.c \
                src/lib_ccx/lib_ccx.h \
                src/lib_ccx/list.h \
                src/lib_ccx/matroska.c \
                src/lib_ccx/matroska.h \
                src/lib_ccx/myth.c \
                src/lib_ccx/networking.c \
                src/lib_ccx/networking.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ocr.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ocr.h \
                src/lib_ccx/output.c \
                src/lib_ccx/params.c \
                src/lib_ccx/params_dump.c \
                src/lib_ccx/sequencing.c \
                src/lib_ccx/spupng_encoder.c \
                src/lib_ccx/spupng_encoder.h \
                src/lib_ccx/stdintmsc.h \
                src/lib_ccx/stream_functions.c \
                src/lib_ccx/teletext.h \
                src/lib_ccx/telxcc.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ts_functions.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ts_functions.h \
                src/lib_ccx/ts_info.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ts_tables.c \
                src/lib_ccx/ts_tables_epg.c \
                src/lib_ccx/utility.c \
                src/lib_ccx/utility.h \
                src/lib_ccx/wtv_constants.h \
                src/lib_ccx/wtv_functions.c \
                src/lib_hash/sha2.c \
                src/lib_hash/sha2.h \
                src/libpng/png.c \
                src/libpng/pngconf.h \
                src/libpng/pngdebug.h \
                src/libpng/pngerror.c \
                src/libpng/pngget.c \
                src/libpng/png.h \
                src/libpng/pnginfo.h \
                src/libpng/pnglibconf.h \
                src/libpng/pngmem.c \
                src/libpng/pngpread.c \
                src/libpng/pngpriv.h \
                src/libpng/pngread.c \
                src/libpng/pngrio.c \
                src/libpng/pngrtran.c \
                src/libpng/pngrutil.c \
                src/libpng/pngset.c \
                src/libpng/pngstruct.h \
                src/libpng/pngtrans.c \
                src/libpng/pngwio.c \
                src/libpng/pngwrite.c \
                src/libpng/pngwtran.c \
                src/libpng/pngwutil.c \
                src/protobuf-c/protobuf-c.c \
                src/protobuf-c/protobuf-c.h \
                src/utf8proc/utf8proc.c \
                src/utf8proc/utf8proc_data.c \
                src/utf8proc/utf8proc.h \
                src/win_iconv/iconv.h \
                src/win_iconv/win_iconv.c \
                src/win_spec_incld/dirent.h \
                src/win_spec_incld/inttypes.h \
                src/win_spec_incld/stdint.h \
                src/zlib/adler32.c \
                src/zlib/compress.c \
                src/zlib/crc32.c \
                src/zlib/crc32.h \
                src/zlib/deflate.c \
                src/zlib/deflate.h \
                src/zlib/gzclose.c \
                src/zlib/gzguts.h \
                src/zlib/gzlib.c \
                src/zlib/gzread.c \
                src/zlib/gzwrite.c \
                src/zlib/infback.c \
                src/zlib/inffast.c \
                src/zlib/inffast.h \
                src/zlib/inffixed.h \
                src/zlib/inflate.c \
                src/zlib/inflate.h \
                src/zlib/inftrees.c \
                src/zlib/inftrees.h \
                src/zlib/trees.c \
                src/zlib/trees.h \
                src/zlib/uncompr.c \
                src/zlib/zconf.h \
                src/zlib/zlib.h \
                src/zlib/zutil.c \
                src/zlib/zutil.h \
                src/zvbi/bcd.h \
                src/zvbi/bit_slicer.c \
                src/zvbi/bit_slicer.h \
                src/zvbi/decoder.c \
                src/zvbi/macros.h \
                src/zvbi/misc.h \
                src/zvbi/raw_decoder.c \
                src/zvbi/raw_decoder.h \
                src/zvbi/sampling_par.c \
                src/zvbi/sampling_par.h \
                src/zvbi/sliced.h \
                src/zvbi/zvbi_decoder.h

ccextractor_CFLAGS =-std=gnu99 -Wno-write-strings -DGPAC_CONFIG_LINUX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVERSION_FILE_PRESENT -DENABLE_OCR

ccextractor_CPPFLAGS =-I /usr/include/leptonica/ -I /usr/include/tesseract/ -I src/lib_ccx/ -I src/gpacmp4/ -I src/libpng/ -I src/zlib/ -I src/zvbi/ -I src/lib_hash/ -I src/protobuf-c/ -I src/utf8proc/

ccextractor_LDADD =-lm -ltesseract -llept

ccextractor_LDFLAGS=-zmuldefs
```

The `build` script which builds "ccextractor" perfectly fine is:

```
#!/bin/bash
BLD_FLAGS="-std=gnu99 -Wno-write-strings -DGPAC_CONFIG_LINUX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVERSION_FILE_PRESENT -DENABLE_OCR"
BLD_INCLUDE="-Isrc -I /usr/include/leptonica/ -I /usr/include/tesseract/ -Isrc/lib_ccx/ -Isrc/gpacmp4/ -Isrc/libpng/ -Isrc/zlib/ -Isrc/zvbi -Isrc/lib_hash -Isrc/protobuf-c -Isrc/utf8proc"
SRC_LIBPNG="$(find src/libpng/ -name '*.c')"
SRC_ZLIB="$(find src/zlib/ -name '*.c')"
SRC_ZVBI="$(find src/zvbi/ -name '*.c')"
SRC_CCX="$(find src/lib_ccx/ -name '*.c')"
SRC_GPAC="$(find src/gpacmp4/ -name '*.c')"
SRC_HASH="$(find src/lib_hash/ -name '*.c')"
SRC_PROTOBUF="$(find src/protobuf-c/ -name '*.c')"
SRC_UTF8PROC="src/utf8proc/utf8proc.c"
BLD_SOURCES="src/ccextractor.c $SRC_CCX $SRC_GPAC $SRC_ZLIB $SRC_ZVBI $SRC_LIBPNG $SRC_HASH $SRC_PROTOBUF $SRC_UTF8PROC"
BLD_LINKER="-lm -zmuldefs -l tesseract -l lept"


**Stripped a call for a script which checks the git commit (nothing that'd interfere with build**

out=$((LC_ALL=C gcc $BLD_FLAGS $BLD_INCLUDE -o ccextractor $BLD_SOURCES $BLD_LINKER) 2>&1)
res=$?
if [[ $out == *"gcc: command not found"* ]]
then
    echo "Error: please install gcc";
    exit 1
fi
if [[ $out == *"curl.h: No such file or directory"* ]]
then
    echo "Error: please install curl development library (libcurl4-gnutls-dev for Debian/Ubuntu)";
    exit 2
fi
if [[ $out == *"capi.h: No such file or directory"* ]]
then
    echo "Error: please install tesseract development library (tesseract-ocr-dev for Debian/Ubuntu)";
    exit 3
fi
if [[ $out == *"allheaders.h: No such file or directory"* ]]
then
    echo "Error: please install leptonica development library (libleptonica-dev for Debian/Ubuntu)";
    exit 4
fi
if [[ $res -ne 0 ]]  # Unknown error
then
    echo "Compiled with errors"
    >&2 echo "$out"
    exit 5
fi
echo "Compilation successful";
```

Here are some initial statements which `make` invokes:

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I /usr/include/leptonica/ -I /usr/include/tesseract/ -I src/lib_ccx/ -I src/gpacmp4/ -I src/libpng/ -I src/zlib/ -I src/zvbi/ -I src/lib_hash/ -I src/protobuf-c/ -I src/utf8proc/  -std=gnu99 -Wno-write-strings -DGPAC_CONFIG_LINUX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVERSION_FILE_PRESENT -DENABLE_OCR -g -O2 -MT src/ccextractor-ccextractor.o -MD -MP -MF src/.deps/ccextractor-ccextractor.Tpo -c -o src/ccextractor-ccextractor.o `test -f 'src/ccextractor.c' || echo './'`src/ccextractor.c
mv -f src/.deps/ccextractor-ccextractor.Tpo src/.deps/ccextractor-ccextractor.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I /usr/include/leptonica/ -I /usr/include/tesseract/ -I src/lib_ccx/ -I src/gpacmp4/ -I src/libpng/ -I src/zlib/ -I src/zvbi/ -I src/lib_hash/ -I src/protobuf-c/ -I src/utf8proc/  -std=gnu99 -Wno-write-strings -DGPAC_CONFIG_LINUX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVERSION_FILE_PRESENT -DENABLE_OCR -g -O2 -MT src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-avc_ext.o -MD -MP -MF src/gpacmp4/.deps/ccextractor-avc_ext.Tpo -c -o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-avc_ext.o `test -f 'src/gpacmp4/avc_ext.c' || echo './'`src/gpacmp4/avc_ext.c
mv -f src/gpacmp4/.deps/ccextractor-avc_ext.Tpo src/gpacmp4/.deps/ccextractor-avc_ext.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I /usr/include/leptonica/ -I /usr/include/tesseract/ -I src/lib_ccx/ -I src/gpacmp4/ -I src/libpng/ -I src/zlib/ -I src/zvbi/ -I src/lib_hash/ -I src/protobuf-c/ -I src/utf8proc/  -std=gnu99 -Wno-write-strings -DGPAC_CONFIG_LINUX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVERSION_FILE_PRESENT -DENABLE_OCR -g -O2 -MT src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-avilib.o -MD -MP -MF src/gpacmp4/.deps/ccextractor-avilib.Tpo -c -o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-avilib.o `test -f 'src/gpacmp4/avilib.c' || echo './'`src/gpacmp4/avilib.c
mv -f src/gpacmp4/.deps/ccextractor-avilib.Tpo src/gpacmp4/.deps/ccextractor-avilib.Po
```

Statement which `make` invokes just before showing undefined reference errors:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -Wno-write-strings -DGPAC_CONFIG_LINUX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVERSION_FILE_PRESENT -DENABLE_OCR -g -O2 -zmuldefs  -o ccextractor src/ccextractor-ccextractor.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-avc_ext.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-avilib.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-av_parsers.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-base_encoding.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-bitstream.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-box_code_3gpp.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-box_code_adobe.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-box_code_apple.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-box_code_base.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-box_code_drm.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-box_code_meta.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-box_funcs.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-configfile.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-data_map.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-desc_private.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-descriptors.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-drm_sample.o src/gpacmp4/ccextractor-error.o -lm -ltesseract -llept

/media/mayank/Mayank/GSOC 2017/Projects/ccextractor/src/ccextractor.c:32: undefined reference to `mprint'
/media/mayank/Mayank/GSOC 2017/Projects/ccextractor/src/ccextractor.c:33: undefined reference to `change_filename_requested'
src/ccextractor-ccextractor.o: In function `sigint_handler':
/media/mayank/Mayank/GSOC 2017/Projects/ccextractor/src/ccextractor.c:47: undefined reference to `print_file_report'
src/ccextractor-ccextractor.o: In function `print_end_msg':
/media/mayank/Mayank/GSOC 2017/Projects/ccextractor/src/ccextractor.c:55: undefined reference to `mprint'
/media/mayank/Mayank/GSOC 2017/Projects/ccextractor/src/ccextractor.c:56: undefined reference to `mprint'
src/ccextractor-ccextractor.o: In function `main':
/media/mayank/Mayank/GSOC 2017/Projects/ccextractor/src/ccextractor.c:68: undefined reference to `init_options'
/media/mayank/Mayank/GSOC 2017/Projects/ccextractor/src/ccextractor.c:70: undefined reference to `parse_configuration'
/media/mayank/Mayank/GSOC 2017/Projects/ccextractor/src/ccextractor.c:71: undefined reference to `parse_parameters'
```

PS: Sorry for the delay in update. Any help is appreciated.I tried many things including changing the path of the `#include <path/to/header>` statements in code and then adding `-I` statement in `CFLAGS` but that didn't help either. Almost all the undefined reference errors are from the functions declared in the headers residing in subdirectories of directories in source like, `src/dir/subdir` the `-I` flags are added only till `src/dir/` and then the files in `src/dir/` have statements like `#include<subdir/filename.h>`.

PPS: I used `grep -r "<Name_of_function_leading_to_error>" .` in `src` to find out the declaration header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show the line make invoked to link your code, which would be very useful.

However, you don't want to put libraries into the `LDLFLAGS` (or `AM_LDLFAGS`) variable; that variable is for linker flags like `-L`, etc.  You should use `LDADD`:

```
LDADD = -lm -lz -ltesseract -llept
```

If you look at the link line that make is generating you'll see all these options coming BEFORE any of your object files on the link line; that's not right.  The GNU binutils ld is a single-pass linker, which means that the order of `-l` flags is very important for proper linking.

Comment: Yes.  Even better, though, would be for `configure` to locate, check, and add the needed libraries, instead of specifying them in `Makefile.am`.  As I'm sure you know, Autoconf has a family of macros for such purposes.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely true.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I'll update `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` and update the question if the problem persists. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @MadScientist a polite ping. I updated the question statement. Can you please help me on it?

Comment: At this point I recommend you just ask a new question.  Your original question has been answered and you've accepted the answer which means people are no longer looking at this as an open question.  Your new problem is different and should get a new question.  Your errors here are link-time errors, not compile-time errors, which means that header files are not relevant.  What matters is ensuring that the object files and libraries that define those functions are available on the link line.